# Unable to load default Nginx start page in browser

Tags: php, nginx

Following this tutorial for setting up a LEMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04, I am unable to load the default page in the browser:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

I am trying to pull up the page by requesting the server IP address in the browser, i.e. typing `http://server_ip_address` into Chrome.

The connection times out. However, I am able to run

```
$ curl server_ip_address
```

and return the html in the terminal.

What am I doing wrong here?

Update: Resolved. Ended up being an issue with Cloudflare; had non-Cloudflare IP addresses blocked. So, there was no Nginx issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you have the service running on the server by using: netstat -lt command
2. If the service is running then check if you have the security group rules against it
3. If both the above conditions are good then try accessing the start page on the port on which  the service is running

Note:

1. Make sure nginx is running on port 80
2. Make sure you stopped apache2

Answer (score 1):

(1)Run "curl" test at another host, not in the ${server_ip_address} itself.    
(2)If you get the right result at step 1, then you will get the same result at chrome.   
(3)Check the firewall of ${server_ip_address} host,such as:

```
netstat -ntpl | grep ${port_of_nginx}
iptables -L -n | grep ${port_of_nginx}
```

Comment: I am able to run a "curl" test on another host with no problems, but Chrome 
(and Internet Explorer) still time out. For now, I have disabled the firewall.

Comment: @Joey, if the curl test is ok, I think you should focus on the network of your Chrome client, just do "ping" test before Chrome visit test, or do Chrome visit test on another machine? Finally, we can start tcpdump on the WEB server to debug this problem.

Comment: Resolved. Ended up being an issue with Cloudflare; had non-Cloudflare IP addresses blocked.